# Python dataframe with date (dates and events)

Tags: python, dataframe, sorting

Using PYTHON, I am trying to sort the values in the table based on dates and the associated events. Date1 and event1 are a pair because event1 occurred on date1. The same for other dates and events.
date1 is in a column of its own, and event1 is also in its own separate column.

For example, the table would include as below:

| date1 | event1 | date2 | event2 | date3 | event3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| March 6, 2021 | eventC | Jan. 1, 2020 | eventX | May 11, 2020 | eventB |
| Dec. 6, 2021 | eventBB | Feb. 11, 2001 | eventYY | June 13, 1990 | eventSS |
| March 16, 2019 | eventCD | Jan. 1, 1998 | eventRE | May 23, 1989 | eventDF |
| Nov. 1, 2008 | eventCC | April 14, 2001 | eventWQ | March 17, 1999 | eventCV |

I would like the result to show as follows where for each row, sort the data from oldest date to the newest, but the order of the events follow their respective dates (e.g. eventC that occurred on March 6, 2021 as the first in row 0 is now reordered to be the third in row 0).

| date1 | event1 | date2 | event2 | date3 | event3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Jan. 1, 2020 | eventX | May 11, 2020 | eventB | March 6, 2021 | eventC |
| June 13, 1990 | eventSS | Feb. 11, 2001 | eventYY | Dec. 6, 2021 | eventBB |
| May 23, 1989 | eventDF | Jan. 1, 1998 | eventRE | March 16, 2019 | eventCD |
| March 17, 1999 | eventCV | Nov. 1, 2008 | eventCC | April 14, 2001 | eventWQ |

I would like to keep the output in the table format as above! (unless there is a good reason not to...)  =)

This is actually a very small version of a much larger data. Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks to all in advance!!!

Comment: It looks like you asked for your homework... you should show some research effort, what you already tried, some piece of codes. People on SO will *not* do your work for you. Pleas consider reading this : https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I am new to stack overflow and do not mean to take advantage of any sort, I am simply asking a question. I do not, however, appreciate people judging based simply on their mere perceptions.  I tried to approach this problem in different ways, including taking only the dates and changing the format to "datetime." But, I am not sure how to do that when the dates to be sorted are in the same ROW, and to make sure that the corresponding events are sorted based on its dates.  If not actual coding, I would also appreciate some guidance in a direction to take or approach this problem... Thanks bunch!

Comment: Did you try, for instance : "sort array by date with python" in a researcher engine ? Or "sort table with date and event in python" ? Or "double column array sorting in python" ? If so, what did you find ? What did you try in code ? I don't suppose anything but it *looks* like somebody asked you something and you just re-write the question here for us to do the job. If its not the case then *show* some research effort. Don't *tell* it.

Answer (score 0):

Cast the '`Dates`' values to `datetime` and use the `sort_values()` function. Example:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([{"Date":"02-01-1945","Name":"event2"},{"Date":"20-11-1934", "Name":"event1"}])
print(df)

#Output:
#
#         Date    Name
#0  02-01-1945  event2
#1  20-11-1934  event1

df["Date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Date"])
df= df.sort_values(by="Date")
print(df)

#Output:
#        Date    Name
#1 1934-11-20  event1
#0 1945-02-01  event2
```

Comment: Thanks, but my question is not about sorting the dates in a single column, rather sorting the dates in multiple columns for each of the rows.